# for loop iteration cant find whats making i jump values

Tags: java

**FILE THATS BEING READ**

```html
Rob Gronkowski 48
Zach Ertz 34
Travis Kelce 29
Evan Engram 15
Jimmy Graham 12
Cameron Brate 10
Delanie Walker 9
Kyle Rudolph 6
Austin Seferian-Jenkins 6
Jack Doyle 6
Hunter Henry 5
Jason Witten 4
Jordan Reed 4
Vernon Davis 3
Jared Cook 3
Tyler Kroft 3
Ed Dickson 3
Charles Clay 3
George Kittle 3
Antonio Brown 67
DeAndre Hopkins 62
A.J. Green 62
Mike Evans 62
Julio Jones 56
Michael Thomas 55
Dez Bryant 53
Michael Crabtree 45
Brandin Cooks 42
Tyreek Hill 42
Doug Baldwin 42
Keenan Allen 32
Jarvis Landry 29
Will Fuller 29
Amari Cooper 29
Stefon Diggs 29
Alshon Jeffery 27
Nelson Agholor 24
Adam Thielen 24
Chris Hogan 24
Golden Tate 24
Demaryius Thomas 22
Jordy Nelson 22
Larry Fitzgerald 22
DeSean Jackson 21
JuJu Smith-Schuster 19
Devante Parker 18
Devin Funchess 18
Kelvin Benjamin 18
T.Y. Hilton 17
Emmanuel Sanders 17
Marvin Jones 15
Rishard Matthews 14
Pierre Garcon 14
Cooper Kupp 14
Sterling Shepard 14
Paul Richardson 11
Danny Amendola 10Le’Veon Bell 70
Kareem Hunt 63
Todd Gurley 63
Leonard Fournette 60
Melvin Gordon 60
LeSean McCoy 60
Mark Ingram 50
Devonta Freeman 50
Jordan Howard 50
Lamar Miller 41
Doug Martin 34
Carlos Hyde 34
Aaron Jones 27
Alvin Kamara 27
Jerick McKinnon 24
DeMarco Murray 21
Chris Thompson 21
Jay Ajayi 21
Joe Mixon 18
C.J. Anderson 17
Tevin Coleman 17 
Christian McCaffrey 17
Derrick Henry 16 
Alex Collins 16
Dion Lewis 15
Adrian Peterson 13
Duke Johnson 12
Marshawn Lynch 11
Ameer Abdullah 10
Bilal Powell 9
LeGarrette Blount 9
Marlon Mack 9
James White 8
Ezekiel Elliott 7
Latavius Murray 7
Frank Gore 7
Isaiah Crowell 7
Orleans Darkwa 7
Kenyan Drake 5
Matt Forte 5
Darren McFadden 5
Alfred Morris 5
Damien Williams 3
Tarik Cohen 3
Jonathan Stewart 3
Robert Kelley 3
Danny Woodhead 3
Ty Montgomery 2
Javorius Allen 2
Mike Gillislee 2
Thomas Rawls 2
Theo Riddick 2
DeAndre Washington 2
Eddie Lacy 2
Giovani Bernard 2
Andre Ellington 2
Austin Ekeler 2
Jalen Richard 2
Ted Ginn 10
Robby Anderson 10
Jermaine Kearse 9
Davante Adams 9
Kenny Stills 9
Sammy Watkins 9
Marqise Lee 5
Mohamed Sanu 5
Allen Hurns 5
Josh Doctson 5
Jamison Crowder 4
Jeremy Maclin 3
Randall Cobb 3
Tyrell Williams 3
Robert Woods 3
Corey Davis 3
Jordan Matthews 3
Tyler Lockett 3
John Brown 2
Willie Snead 2
Donte Moncrief 2
Deshaun Watson 31
Dak Prescott 26
Tom Brady 24
Russell Wilson 22
Drew Brees 22
Carson Wentz 20
Alex Smith 14
Kirk Cousins 13
Matthew Stafford 11
Marcus Mariota 11
Tyrod Taylor 11
Cam Newton 11
Matt Ryan 11
Philip Rivers 8
```

having some problems been looking all over for answers. I found out my for loop iteration is incorrect it prints the series:0,1,2,10 etc. I was wondering if someone can point out my flaw, so I can fix this. I apprectiate anyone reading this, and appolgozie for the length of code. But just wanted to include everything so I don't miss anything. **FOR LOOP LINE 87** thanks again, sincerely java noob

**CODE**

```
package trades;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Fantasy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] playerRanking = new int[75];   
        String infoComingIn = null;
        //Finding file path
        String filename = "C:\\Users\\Karanvir\\Desktop\\21days\\players.txt";
        File filez = new File(filename);

        BufferedReader br;    
        String[] playerNames = new String[75];    
        int counterOfReadLines = 0;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{2,3}");

        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filez));    
            playerNames[counterOfReadLines] = br.readLine();

            while (br.readLine() != null) {
                counterOfReadLines = counterOfReadLines + 1;
                playerNames[counterOfReadLines] = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(playerNames[counterOfReadLines - 1]);
            }
            br.close(); 

            for (int i = 0; i < playerNames.length; i++) {
                Matcher m = p.matcher(playerNames[i]);

                if (m.find()) {
                    String matched = m.group(0);
                    int addToArray = Integer.parseInt(matched);
                    playerRanking[i] = addToArray;
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: If there was ever a case for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I think this is it :)

Comment: I wanted to include a small snipit, but last time I tried that I was told its not enough. my bad but its line 87

Comment: @gottaassk please include the expected and actual output and explain what exactly is wrong

Comment: We still can't reproduce the issue, but note that you only print `i` when the `if` is true. Thus you don't print every `i`.

Comment: Since we can't guess what's in `players.txt` and which line is line 87, and what's the issue you're having - it's a bit difficult to help you...

Comment: God knows that this: `catch (Exception e) {}` is flying blind. Please don't do this. As for your actual problem -- again handle your exceptions by at least printing the stacktrace and then use a debugger to isolate the problem. Then use that information to create and post a valid [mcve].  Do this *before* coming here.

Comment: im adding my file being read right now

Comment: Please look guys added the file that's being read

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so by seeing the post, I can point out only one issue. Since you are incrementing counterOfReadLines variable before the line

playerNames[counterOfReadLines] = br.readLine();

so what happens is playerNames is initializing with the array of index 1 not 0 and when you are trying to call the loop below:-
 for (int i = 0; i < playerNames.length; i++) {
                Matcher m = p.matcher(playerNames[i]);

```
            if (m.find()) {
                String matched = m.group(0);
                int addToArray = Integer.parseInt(matched);
                playerRanking[i] = addToArray;
                System.out.println(i);
            }
```

it is incrementing with 0. So either start it from i=1 or increment the counterOfReadLines  after the line
playerNames[counterOfReadLines] = br.readLine();

so your error will go away...! if not let me know... :) !

Comment: No sorry doesn't work, my array index initialize is at zero +

Comment: try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filez));    
     --->remove this     playerNames[counterOfReadLines] = br.readLine();

            while (br.readLine() != null) {
  interchange  -->    counterOfReadLines = counterOfReadLines + 1;
     these two -->   playerNames[counterOfReadLines] = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(playerNames[counterOfReadLines - 1]);
            }
            br.close();

Comment: it wont work because if I remove the while loop, I wont be adding my information into my array

Comment: My playerNames array is all good, it works perfectly. It adds everyone into my array with the correct index. Its my playerRanking that wont work. Something to do with iteration , or maybe the regex is incorrect.

Comment: the problem is with 'i' value for playerrank, you need to create a variable k and then increment k only when the data will be added to that list.

int k=0;

 for (int i = 0; i < playerNames.length; i++) {
                Matcher m = p.matcher(playerNames[i]);
                if (m.find()) {
                    String matched = m.group(0);
                    int addToArray = Integer.parseInt(matched);
                    playerRanking[k] = addToArray;
                    k++;
System.out.println(k);
                }
            }

This will work perfectly now... check this out.